iPhone 15 Pro Max suddenly started to lose battery much faster than before
I’m using an iPhone 15 Pro Max with iOS 18.1.
For the past two or three days, it’s been losing battery way faster than normal.
Also (and I don’t know if this is connected), my screen time tracker seems to think the phone is always in use.


Also, the app that’s been most used for the past couple weeks is Settings.

I assure you I haven’t used the phone anywhere near that much.
Before this, my battery life was much more normal. Also, as I write this question (which has taken around 2 minutes), I have lost 6%, which is much worse than normal).
The phone’s been at what seems to be normal temperature. It hasn’t been slow at all. I close all tabs in my browser, and close the tabs of all apps. Nothing is using my location or Bluetooth.

When did you last power it down cleanly? It’s not normal for settings app to be stuck like that so a little troubleshooting will likely sort this out. Is it backed up?

@bmike It’s backed up, and I’ve powered it down twice after posting this question - no fix.

I read your setting app going 100% mid day Monday and not relenting yet. I would restore my device at this point to check (not restoring the backup initially). It should be fairly easy to know if it’s still stuck on after a couple hours with a clean setup, no iCloud, no apps, just charging.
